# .Net MAUI - Page\View load missing flyout menu option

Tags: c#, navigation, maui, maui-shell

I have a simple Maui app.
I have a flyout menu that works well and navigates to the required Views.
However when I try to load a view (UserHomeScreen) from a button click event in another view (LoginScreen) the flyout menu icon doesn't  appear (although the back button does) even though it appears if I load the view from the flyout menu..

My XAML (App.Shell.xaml):

```
<FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems" Route="ParentRoute" >
        <ShellContent
        Title="Login"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Views.LoginScreen}"/>
    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems" Route="ParentRoute">
        <ShellContent
        Title="Home Screen"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Views.UserHomeScreen}"/>
    </FlyoutItem>
```

My code behind (AppShell.cs) :

```
public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(LoginScreen), typeof(LoginScreen));
        
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(UserHomeScreen ), typeof(UserHomeScreen ));
           
    }
```

My XAML (LoginScreen.xaml):

```
<Button x:Name="btnLoginOK" Text=" OK" Background="White" TextColor="Blue" WidthRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="End" Clicked="btnLoginOK_Clicked" />
```

My code behind (LoginScreen.xaml.cs):

```
private async void btnLoginOK_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
                await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(UserHomeScreen));
    }
```

But for some reason if I load UserHomeScreen from the flyout menu I get the flyout menu icon. If I load UserHomScreen from the button click (btnLoginOK_Clicked) i dont...

Any ideas what im missing or doing wrong??

Comment: 1. May I know what platform you are targeting? 2. Have you set `Shell.FlyoutBehavior = Flyout` in App.Shell.xaml?

Comment: Android and ios and yes I have.. the menu option doesn't appear, its as if the page/view (when loaded via the button) is somehow outside the shell (which I know is ridiculous)

Comment: Although oddly I've just tested on windows and the problem doesn't occur on windows..

Comment: It's as of the back button is hiding the menu button

Comment: Thanks for the update. You can see my answer below.

Comment: Thankyou that worked - still not 100% sure why , but ill figure that out..

Thankyou Alexandar May - MSFT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the correct way to do the navigation that preserves the flyout menu (hamburger icon) via a Button. Note that sample code guarantees the consistency across three platforms: Android, iOS and Windows.

```
<FlyoutItem  Title="Login" >
        <Tab>
            <ShellContent
        Title="Login"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Views.LoginScreen}" Route="LoginScreen"/>
        </Tab>
 </FlyoutItem>

<FlyoutItem  Title="Home Screen">
      <Tab>
         <ShellContent
        Title="Home Screen"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Views.UserHomeScreen}" Route="UserHomeScreen"/>

        </Tab>
</FlyoutItem>
```

```
private async void btnLoginOK_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
     await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(UserHomeScreen)}");
}
```

And comment out below in AppShell.cs:

```
//Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(LoginScreen), typeof(LoginScreen));
        
//Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(UserHomeScreen), typeof(UserHomeScreen ));
```